# How to addChild to a movie clip a movie clip that as bitmap in it

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am trying to create a list in runtime but couldn't make it work.

Here is my code :

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(mc);
grpList.source = mc;
for(var i = 0;i<count;i++){
    var img:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new listbitmap(0,0));
    var mvc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    mvc.height = img.height;
    mvc.width = img.width;
    mvc.x = 0;
    mvc.y = i * 100;
    mvc.addChild(img);
    mc.addChild(mvc);
    grpItemList.update();
}
```

I have a scroll pane and inside of it i have a movie clip. In that movie clip i want to list new movie clips that has bitmaps in it. 
When i try to do it without a new movie clip but adding the image directly, it works like a charm.
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I think,the problem is asigning the dimensions before the movieclip has content. Further you dont need to set the dimensions to the dimensions of the only child. The `mvc` gets height and width of the attached image automatically.

Comment: @AndreLehnert Thank you so much. That fixed it. Please change your comment to an answer so that i can approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think,the problem is asigning the dimensions before the movieclip has content. Further you dont need to set the dimensions to the dimensions of the only child. The mvc gets height and width of the attached image automatically.
Greetings.